# How to glob import css files to scoped style tag in Vue 3/Vite?

Tags: vuejs3, vite

Need to glob import css files from a dependent module to a component's scoped <style>. Conceptually,

```html
<!-- file myComponent.vue -->

<style scoped lang="less">
#myId {
  /* glob doesn't work for @import inlining by default. */
  @import (less) 'foo_module/src/**/*.css'; 
}
</style>

<template>...</template>
<script>...</script>
```

I found two potential solutions:

1. [*postcss-import-ext-glob*](https://github.com/dimitrinicolas/postcss-import-ext-glob) plugin. I added to *vite.config.js*

   ```
   css: {
     postcss: [require('postcss-import-ext-glob'), require('postcss-import')]
   }
   ```

   and using `@import-glob` in *myComponent.vue* but doesn't work.
2. `import.meta.glob`. I can get the css as object and can convert to string. but don't know how to inject the object/string to <style> tag:

   ```html
   <!-- file myComponent.vue -->   
   <script>
     const cssObjs = import.meta.glob(
       '/node_modules/foo_module/src/**/*.css', 
       { as: 'raw', eager: true },
     );
     const concatenatedCssStr = Object.values(cssObjs).join('\n');
     export default {
       data: function () {
         return {
           concatenatedCssStr 
         };
       },
     }
   </script>

   <style scoped lang="less">
   #myId {
     /* string interpolation doesn't work in style */
     {{ concatenatedCssStr }} 
   }
   </style>
   ```

Anyone figured out how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The source code on my github](https://github.com/silentmantra/vite-inject-css)

You cannot inject styles into your SFC component the way you tried.
The only solution I see for now is a custom Rollup plugin with simple string replacing:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import fs from 'fs';
import { globSync } from 'fast-glob';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        {
            load(id) {
                if (id.endsWith('.vue')) {
                    const source = fs.readFileSync(id).toString().replace(/inject-css:\s*"([^"]+)";/g, replace => {
                        const pattern = replace.match(/"([^"]+)/)[1];
                        return globSync(pattern, { absolute: true }).map(file => fs.readFileSync(file)).join(';');
                    });
                    return source;
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    }
})
```

App.vue (style section):

```
<style scoped>

header {
    inject-css: "./src/components/**/*.css";
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

./src/components/test.css

```
* {
    background: green !important;
    color: red;
}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: @abbr wrote a rollup plugin, works fine. if you need the source code, let me know

Comment: With slight modification of the code in answer, it works for me so I'll accept it as answer. If you want to publish it as a vite/rollup plugin, more polish is probably needed, including:
1. support both single and double quote
2. auto-prefix node_modules for deps same as @import
3. a more IDE formatter friendly syntax. `inject-css` is not a valid directive recognized by formatter.

Comment: @abbr thanks for your feedback, glad we solved that together. since it's solved don't hesitate to upvote my answer also (the arrow up) will be much appreciated. Also regarding my code - it was a quick fast solution to give you an idea how it could be implemented. Yes, your remarks are valuable and there should be improvements how to make IDE calm with these injections. I'd like to know your example implementation. You could post an issue on my github repository and we could small discussion there.